# ASP.Net Web application dll loading issue

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

I have a custom dll loaded into my web application, I updated it and reloaded the reference in my main web app.  Basically the way it works is a user uploads a file that gets checked by a function in the dll.  The user can then click a button on the results section that redirects to the main section of the app so they have a choice of rerunning the checker; I say section because the web app uses a single page with two divs, one for the form and one for the results, the code behind then swaps the visibility of the form div from the results div, here's the basic layout to clarify.

```
<body>
  <div id="divForm" style="visibility: visible;">
  </div>

<div id="divResults">
  </div>
</body>
```

The redirect call is in the code behind as follows:

```
protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("http://localhost/file_checker/");
        }
```

And the main piece of the file checker:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    divForm.Visible = true;
    divResults.Visible = false;
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       //Do file checking

       //Show results
       divResults.Visible = true;
       divForm.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

The web app works fine on the first pass, however, I notice strange behavior after every subsequent pass.  For example, I notice that the results page shows stale content from an older version of dll, i.e. It displays a string that was generated by an older version of the dll, I had removed the string and yet it still gets generated.  I'm not sure if I'm redirecting correctly or if there's some other fundamental misunderstanding I have with how redirects work.  Any help or insight is appreciated.

UPDATE:

Ok, instead of redirecting, I just cleared a gridview in my results section and swapped the styles of the divs to show the main section and hide the results section as follows:

```
protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Clear the Gridview and show the upload Form
            GridView1.DataSource = null; //<--Is popoulated by a DataTable
            divForm.Visible = true;
            divResults.Visible = false;

            //Response.Redirect("http://localhost/file_checker/");
        }
```

That seems to fix the problem, a lingering question I have is, I'm using a Datatable to populate the Gridview in the results page.  Does the Datatable automatically dispose itself after each page load or button click event?  Or will it persist?  I just want to avoid any memory leak issues, since each page load instantiates a new DataTable object.

Comment: What is "Visibility: hidden"?  Looks like CSS, but its not in a style="" attribute.

Comment: I assumed psuedocode. He would also need runat="server" and visible="true" or visible="false" in the aspx page to make this work.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct, there is not visibility hidden.  You can ignore, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

A Response.Redirect sends a 302 response to the browser. The browser then makes a new request to the new location. So it isn't a server side operation, and the browser can cache the response and not make the call again. Try appending a querystring parameter to make the browser do a true request. If you have fiddler available, you might use that to verify, but you are probably getting the page from cache.

```
protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("http://localhost/file_checker/?{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks));
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry what is fiddler exactly?

Comment: it's a web debugging proxy. With it you can watch the requests your browser is making and see the server response. It's a very handy tool to have for debugging websites and especially those using ajax. You can get it here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks NerdFury, I'll look into it.  I got recalled to another project, but I'll get back to this later today.  Appreciate the help.